# Find all Values on the event handler as the parameter e

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a form and I want  all values of my eventInfo on a Array , Is it possible  ?

I have this   :

```
function doPost(eventInfo) {  

     var submited = eventInfo.values;
       Logger.log(submited);   // undefined
       Logger.log(eventInfo.parameter) //  all Informations

    // Code 
     return app;
    }
```

I use this :

```
Logger.log(EventInfo.parameter);
```

I have this my console:

```
 {D Machines tank repair=interesting, appId=..., 
 DS Pad ownership=rejected, 
 Alloy output heating system=implemented, 
 Dip Coating Module Leak Detection=implemented, 
 Zirkonium pills=implemented, 
 gm1xs=, lib=..., 
 Theory of Constraints Training=interesting, 
 DSPC Spheric Lens Reuse=interesting, 
 formId=form, token=..., 
 Hardcoat - Connecting Processes=rejected, 
 service=..., 
 Varnish Consumption Reduction=implemented, 
 Water saving in Generator cleaning=interesting}
```

For Exemple , I have this :
Water saving in Generator cleaning=interesting

How can I use automatically this because I want this array  ?

```
Array[0][0] = Water saving in Generator cleaning; 
Array[0][1] = interesting;
```

Comment: have you tried to ask Google ? search for "how to list all properties of a javascript object"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick [search on Google](https://www.google.be/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20to%20list%20all%20properties%20of%20a%20javascript%20object) returns a lot of results...

An example using [onEdit in a spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events) :

```
function onEdit(e) {
  for(var propertyName in e) {
    Logger.log(propertyName + ' = ' + e[propertyName]);
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Serge Insas.

You helped me for your solution.

You solution is not working for me :

```
function onEdit(e) {
  for(var propertyName in e) {
    Logger.log(propertyName + ' = ' + e[propertyName]);
  }
}
```

My log :

```
[14-06-30 10:11:32:469 CEST] parameter = [object Object]
[14-06-30 10:11:32:469 CEST] contextPath = 
[14-06-30 10:11:32:469 CEST] contentLength = 1278
```

But if you take this solution :

```
 for(var propertyName in e.parameter) {
    Logger.log(propertyName + ' = ' + e.parameter[propertyName]);
  }
```

My log :

```
    [14-06-30 10:11:32:471 CEST] Alloy output heating system = implemented
    [14-06-30 10:11:32:471 CEST] Dip Coating Module Leak Detection = implemented
    [14-06-30 10:11:32:471 CEST] Zirkonium pills = implemented
```

Comment: it is indeed a "second level parameter", ie a parameter being an object that has parameters itself. Thx for accepting